# SQL Query : Using JOINS with CASE Statement

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio, automation, sqlserver

I've 3 DE

1. MASTER DE with fields SubscriberKey(PK), donottrack, Createddate, Modifieddate
2. Staging DE with field CustomerID(PK), Createddate
3. Reference DE with field donottrack default value false.

SubscriberKey would be like - 10digit(numeric)_emailId and CustomerId - 10digit(numeric).

I'm able to solve the above problem statement with CROSS JOIN. Below is my Queries

```
    Select a.SubscriberKey,
b.Created_Date,
b.Last_Modified_Date,
CASE WHEN LEFT (a.SubscriberKey,10) = (b.Customer_ID) THEN b.DoNotTrack
     
     ELSE r.DoNotTrack

END as DoNotTrack
from ent.[STAGING_DE2] a
LEFT JOIN
ent.[MASTER_CUSTOMER_CONSENT_DATA] b
ON LEFT (a.SubscriberKey,10) = (b.Customer_ID)

CROSS JOIN ent.[ReferenceDE] r
```

But If I don't want to use CROSS JOIN, Just want to save Result of 1st half of SQL in DE and then again write 1 more SQL query to update the value of DonotTrack field with value from other DE. How could I do that?. It will look like something below,

1st SQL result stored in DE :

```
Select a.SubscriberKey,
b. DoNotTrack,
a.Created_Date,
a.Last_Modified_Date
from ent.[STAGING_DE2] a
LEFT JOIN
ent.[MASTER_CUSTOMER_CONSENT_DATA] b
ON LEFT (a.SubscriberKey,10) = b.Customer_ID
```

2nd SQL will update the same DE, but took value of DonotTrack from Reference DE, query I'm trying to build like - I'm able to solve this too, see my below query

```
Select a.SubscriberKey,
a.Created_Date,
a.Last_Modified_Date,
r.DoNotTrack as DoNotTrack

FROM ent.[RESULTING_DE] a

FULL JOIN ent.[ReferenceDE] r

ON 1=1

WHERE a.DoNotTrack = 'False'
```

Since I was not having any common field in above both DE, but I just want to reference the Donottrack value from Reference DE, I've applied above solution and it worked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256848/can-i-use-case-statement-in-a-join-condition . Should help you!

Comment: Thanks for the comment Swati, but it's not the specific use case I'm looking for.

Comment: Your first LEFT JOIN does not have an ON statement but is followed by a FULL JOIN.

Comment: Please update your question to include a list of the fields in `ent.[ReferenceDE]`.

Comment: Hi @AdamSpriggs - In ReferenceDE, there would be only one field which is "DonotTrack" and I created on record in this DE just to reference the value of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of details about `ent.[ReferenceDE]`, here's my interpretation:

For all rows in `Staging_DE2` that match a row in `ent.[ReferenceDE]` use the `DoNotTrack` value from `ent.[ReferenceDE]`, otherwise use the `DoNotTrack` value from `Staging_DE2`.

```sql
Select 
  a.SubscriberKey
, b.Created_Date
, b.Last_Modified_Date
, case 
     when r.SubscriberKey is null then a.DoNotTrack
     else r.DoNotTrack
  end DoNotTrack
from ent.[STAGING_DE2] a
left join ent.[ReferenceDE] r ON r.SubscriberKey = LEFT(a.SubscriberKey,10)
```

Or it could be simpler with a COALESCE, which returns the first non-null value in from the specified fields/expressions:

```sql
Select 
  a.SubscriberKey
, b.Created_Date
, b.Last_Modified_Date
, coalesce(r.DoNotTrack,a.DoNotTrack) DoNotTrack 
from ent.[STAGING_DE2] a
left join ent.[ReferenceDE] r ON r.SubscriberKey = LEFT(a.SubscriberKey,10)
```

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for the reply. So in reference DE there would be only one field which is DonotTrack.

I'm doing left join Staging DE with Master DE based on subscriberKey first 10 digit. If the record of Staging DE is not present in Master DE, 

then get the value of DonotTrack as False which is default set in Reference DE. There would be no other field in Reference DE apart from this.

The catch here we are going to have like 200 queries so we cannot set False as Donot track if we don't found in Master. Instead of that we will just change reference DE value,that will flow in each query.